# 10 red cards and 30 black cards, draw a couple of cards 20 times without replacement. but the 20 drawings of couples are with replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I got a deck with 10 red cards and 30 black cards.

Now, I draw a couple of cards 20 times. I draw the couple *without* replacement, but  the 20 drawings of couples are *with* replacement (I restore the original deck at every couple drawing).

Now, what is the probability of obtaining *at least* one time a couple of reds?

Let me to discuss the probability of obtain a couple of reds exactly one time: It seems to me we got to suppose that this probability is hypergeometrically distributed, for a single couple is drawn without replacement. So, $\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{40}{2}}=\frac{3}{52}.$
This result is confirmed by the simplier calculation $\frac{10}{40}\times\frac{9}{39}=\frac{3}{52}.$

Now my intuitive view of sample space is constructed associating an index to each card (reds having indexes from 1 to 10), and squaring this set of integers. Hereby, I obtain the set of all ordered couples, 1600, of which only 100 are composed by two reds. So, drawing a couple at random from this set, gives $\frac{1}{16}$, which is conflicting with previous results. **Why?**

Regarding the probability of draw **at least** a couple of reds over 20 couple drawings, I am unsure. Any suggestion? Perhaps using limit of probabilities of unions of nested events??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of drawing a pair of reds is $\frac{10}{40}\cdot\frac{9}{39}=\frac{3}{52}$. Hence the probability of *not* drawing two reds is $1-\frac{3}{52}$. Thus, the probability of not drawing a pair of reds $20$ times is $\left(1-\frac{3}{52}\right)^{20}$ and finally, the probability of drawing a pair of reds at least once is
$$1-\left(1-\frac{3}{52}\right)^{20}\approx 0.695,$$
according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%2849/52%29%5E20).

Comment: Thanks; Further questions. There are other ways to solve this problem, **without** using the probability of complement set? And, what is wrong with my reasoning about taking the 100 ordered reds over the entire sample space of 1600 ordered couples?

Comment: You are supposed to draw couples of *distinct* cards, as a consequence of drawing them without replacement. On the diagonal of your square 40 by 40 the cards are not distinct.

Comment: You are right! Thanks.